# Cypress - How to count Number of Buttons in a Div?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to find a way to count the number of buttons within a given div, right now the html looks something like this:

```
<div class="Button_List"></div>
    <div class="Button_Container">
        <button class="button1"></button>
        <button class="button2"></button>
        <button class="button3"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Cypress Assertion looks something like this:

```
cy
  .find('.Button_Container')
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 3)
```

Cypress keeps saying it only find one item though: `expected 1 to equal 3`

I'm new to Cypress/Automation in general so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Recommend reading [best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements) to learn more about selectors selection.

Answer (score 2):

This works to check a count of items:

```
cy.get('.Button_Container').find('button').should('have.length', 3)
```

or

```
cy.get('.Button_Container').find('button').its('length').should('eq', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much everyone for the suggestions! Turns out the REAL issue was that the Button Container was inside of an iframe (Cypress + iframes = headaches) so I had to use the iframe library to locate the container and THEN use the following solution:

`cy.frameLoaded('.iframeClass').find('button').its('length').should('eq', 3)`

Answer (score 0):

In case you just have these three buttons on your webpage you can directly check their length using the `button` selector.

```js
cy.get('button').its('length').should('eq', 3)
```

You can apply other assertions as well based on the length like:

1. Greater than 3

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container').find('button').its('length').should('be.gt', 3)
```

2. Greater than and equal to 3

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container').find('button').its('length').should('be.gte', 3)
```

3. Less than 3

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container').find('button').its('length').should('be.lt', 3)
```

4. Less than or equal to 3

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container').find('button').its('length').should('be.lte', 3)
```

5. In some range e.g. Between 1 and 3

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container')
  .find('button')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    expect(len).to.be.within(1, 3) //1 and 3 are also included in the check
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add `.children()` selector

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container')
  .children()
  .should('have.length', 3)
```

If there were other children which are not buttons, filter the children by tag

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container')
  .children('button')
  .should('have.length', 3)
```

---

**Some more variations to try out**

1. Using button class values:

```js
cy.get('button[class^="button"]')  // any button having a class starting with "button"
  .should('have.length', 3)
```

2. Combining selectors:

```js
cy.get('.Button_Container button')  // note the two selectors are separated by a space
  .should('have.length', 3)
```

3. Using higher parent:

```js
cy.get('.Button_List button')  // note the two selectors are separated by a space
  .should('have.length', 3)
```

#3 assumes the HTML is

```html
<div class="Button_List">
    <div class="Button_Container">
        <button class="button1"></button>
        <button class="button2"></button>
        <button class="button3"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```